# Which strategy to build test data

Tags: java, unit-testing

I am new in the development world and i am wondering which are the best strategy to build consistent and coherent complex test data (I mean my POJO are complex to fill) for Unit Testing?

I have heard about "Test Data Builder" but too little topic speak about it on the Net.

Answer (score 0):

I often need to do exactly the same task.  [Fuzz testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) is a suitable approach, though we should be careful to distinguish between raw fuzzers and smart fuzzers.  A smart fuzzer differs from a normal fuzz tool (like [zzuf](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/zzuf)) in that it produces data targeted to your application.  Obviously in this case, you want a smart fuzzer.

To write a smart fuzzer, you'll need to extract those rules that represent "consistent and coherent" and have them as logic.  Probably best to give an example.  The `Model` class below has some logic against it.

```
class Model {

    // Should always be between 0 and 10
    int a;

    // Children
    List<Model> children;

    // Only true at the root
    boolean isRoot;
}
```

We can write a test data builder for this by just codifying those rules.

```
class ModelGenerator {
   private Random random;

   // A seed is a good idea; you want your tests to be reproducible
   public ModelGenerator(int seed) {
       random = new Random(seed);
   }

   public Model arbitrary () {
       return generateSingleItem(true);
   }

   private Model generateSingleItem(boolean isRoot) {
       Model model = new Model();
       model.isRoot = isRoot;
       model.a = random.nextInt(10);

       int childrenCount = random.nextInt(100);
       model.children = new ArrayList<Model>(childrenCount);
       for (int i=0;i<childrenCount;++i) {
            model.children.add(generateSingleItem(false));
       }

       return model;
   }
}
```

Now you can use the generator to create random (but predictable thanks to the seed) models for you to test assertions with.

This approach is very closely related to [QuickCheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck).  There is a [Java version](http://java.net/projects/quickcheck/pages/Home) available which provides a common interface (and more!) the kind of approach described above.

Comment: Thanks for your response but before testing the robustness of my application, i need to provide viable data for the unit-tests.

Comment: I guess I must have explained myself very poorly, sorry!  In the example above, ModelGenerator creates data for your unit tests.

Comment: Ok if i understand you, your approach looks like this describe on this website : [link](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) ?

Comment: Similar yes, but not quite the same.  I think the ObjectMother pattern (which I hadn't seen before, so thanks for the link!) just focuses on generating a single set of objects, whereas the generator approach I'm advocating generates random (but satisfying some constraints) objects.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your time, if you are interested by "Object Mother" pattern you will may be more interested by the "Test Data Builder" pattern discribe here [link](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html), have a look to this [one](http://code.google.com/p/make-it-easy/) too. If you are some times please give me your feedback.

Comment: Great links, thanks.  Those links provide cool builder interfaces for building the code, but they still don't capture the logic (consistent and coherent as you mentioned).  I guess you could combine the two approaches and use a builder interface to generate random (but consistent objects).